# Страница не найдена OpenCart

Tags: opencart

Ребят такая беда, установил модуль экспорта YML, и теперь перестало отображаться страница "Каналы продвижения". Пишет, что страница не найдена. У меня стоит версия 2.0.3.0. Сам модуль установился, но во вкладке Модули/Модификаторы возле yandex модуля пишет, что "Converted to 2.3.0.2". Я так понимаю, что ошибка из-за разных версий модуля и сайта ?

Answer (score 0):

Структура папок в opencart версий 2.0 и 2.3 различна, экстеншн под 2.3 ищет пути, отличные от ваших. Вы понимаете верно.